# will permalink structure change lead to 404 error image galleries created using jetpack?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks, jetpack

Will changing permalink structure of my wordpress posts affect the images posted in gallery format using wordpress jetpack? I mean, if i change the permalink structure, will the images return 404 error with jetpack stil being installed? Or, do I need to remove jetpack before i make changes to my permalink structure?

Comment: I think it will be better if you change the permalink to your liking after installing Jetpack.

Comment: I might just give it a try.